# django and guppy to find which import needs more memory

Tags: django, profiling

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.toofishes.net/blog/using-guppy-debug-django-memory-leaks/) in order to install guppy and profile my django app. My django app does not have a memory leak but for some strange reason it demands much memory in an Apache/mod_wsgi environment. I was told that one of my imports that might be the cause of this problem.

How can I see which import consumes more memory using guppy? guppy output is not so informative for my level. Here it is:

```
*** Connection 1 opened ***
<Monitor> lc
CID PID  ARGV
  1 2056 ['manage.py', 'runserver']
<Monitor> sc 1
Remote connection 1. To return to Monitor, type <Ctrl-C> or .<RETURN>
<Annex> int
Remote interactive console. To return to Annex, type '-'.
>>> hp.heap()
GC hook object was referred to from somebody!
Partition of a set of 128202 objects. Total size = 11015508 bytes.
 Index  Count   %     Size   % Cumulative  % Kind (class / dict of class)
     0  55746  43  4117640  37   4117640  37 str
     1  29278  23  1272920  12   5390560  49 tuple
     2   2457   2   777324   7   6167884  56 dict (no owner)
     3    495   0   583860   5   6751744  61 dict of module
     4   8361   7   501660   5   7253404  66 function
     5   7202   6   489736   4   7743140  70 types.CodeType
     6   1026   1   461748   4   8204888  74 type
     7   1022   1   402472   4   8607360  78 dict of type
     8    179   0   250852   2   8858212  80 dict of django.db.models.fields.CharField
     9   2599   2   156124   1   9014336  82 list
<486 more rows. Type e.g. '_.more' to view.>
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW. There is no specific reason why a Python web application would consume more memory under Apache/mod_wsgi than under a different WSGI server such as uWSGI or gunicorn. The per process memory requirements for the web application under comparable configuration should be about the same as your application isn't going to run any differently. About the only thing which might make a difference is whether the server configuration is multithreaded and you are comparing to a single threaded configuration.

Also be careful what measure of memory you are looking at. Use RSS and not virtual memory size. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Memory_Constrained_VPS_Systems